# What kind of widget is this? / How to make this widget?

Tags: gtk, gnome, glade, pygobject

I've looked through every single widget on glade trying to replicate this "box/table" style seen here on Settings:

[image: Screenshot of Settings on Adwaita Dark and Arc Dark]

But I haven't found anything like it anywhere on Glade or on the official docs :(

The closest I've come to replicating it is through a frame without a label and with separators and custom css that changes the background color to `@base-color`, and although it kinda works alright in some themes:

[image: Replica with Arc Dark]

In others it just plain doesn't work:

[image: Replica with Adwaita Dark]

And I'd imagine that with more elaborate or complex themes it will look even worse.

So my questions are: What is the name of this Widget shown in these pictures? And if it does not exist or is not available in Glade, is there a way to replicate it more reliably than what I've shown here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a [GtkListBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html). As you can see, it takes any other widget as a child. So you have to add rows to the ListBox and then add widgets to each row.

Here is an example in [Python](https://github.com/syohex/python-gtk-tutorial/blob/master/r5/listbox_example.py).

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for.

Although, does Glade currently not support List Boxes? Because I can't seem to find List Box Rows anywhere and it does seem kind of buggy trying to insert one in Glade, and since I've already made the rest of my application through Glade and just plug it with the builder I'd say rewriting it in Python would definitely not be ideal...

Comment: **EDIT:** After much struggle and digging around in menus upon menus, I finally found this [little arrow fella](https://i.imgur.com/nSfVlce.png) on the bottom left part of the screen that is sometimes bugged behind another icon that pops the menu to add a _List Box Row_. That was way more intuitive than it needed to be :S

Comment: I usually create a Listbox in my main Window (or whatever), then right click the Listbox and the bottom menu option is Add Row. Right click does a lot of stuff in Glade, but I do see that little arrow fella is quite handy too. So in the end, I learn from you too :)